# Socket Error 10060 while connecting to IO Modules

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, socketexception

I am communicating between PC and IO modules with TCP connection over ethernet using Modbus protocol. I am using System.Net.Sockets.Socket class for opening and sending/receiving data. At first everything is fine. After some time(5 to 10 hours) I get the following SocketException with error code 10060 when the program calls Socket.Connect method. I try to reconnect after I get the exception but same exception is thrown.

*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

During the normal execution(in the 5-10 hour duration before exception is thrown) I create a new tcp connection by closing old sockets and creating new ones. This is done many times. I check the number of tcp connections every time I reconnect and it stays same. I use the following method to connect many times where SocketWrapper is the class that I use to connect to modules and send/receive data.

How can I investigate this issue?

```
class SocketWrapper
{
    IPAddress m_ipAddr;
    Socket m_Socket;
    int m_port;

    public bool Connect(string i_szIPAddr, ProtocolType protocolType)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Disconnect();
            this.m_ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(i_szIPAddr);

            this.m_port = 0x1f6;
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(this.m_ipAddr, this.m_port);
            this.m_socket = new Socket(remoteEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            this.m_socket.Connect(remoteEP);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (this.m_socket != null)
        {
            if(this.m_socket.Connected)
                this.m_socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

            this.m_socket.Close();
            this.m_socket = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That means the other end didn't respond in time.  Without the code that responds to the connection, we'd be grasping at straws.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I don't have access to that code. It is in the module. Isn't socket connection establishment is a standard procedure?

Comment: So how do you get it going again?  Are you powering down the I/O modules so they get a hard reset?  Firmware has bugs too.